# ¿ Qué código de estado http retornar?

Tags: php, https

tengo un backend que lo que hace es hacer una consulta a la base de datos dependiendo del parametro que ha recibido, sin embargo el valor del parametro puede no existir en la base de datos y no se que error deba retornar, un 400 o un 500?

```
    $service = $_POST['service'];
    $q = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM servicios WHERE servicio = '$service'");
    $r = mysqli_fetch_array($q);

    if($r != NULL){
        var_dump(intval($r['id'],10));
    }else{
        return http_response_code() // codigo de error
    }
```

me dicen que retorne un `200 OK` pero como hago para mostrarle al cliente que hubo un error, ya que el parametro puede ser modificado, por eso es que puede no existir en la base de datos

Comment: Aquí https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status te puedes informar y determinar cual es el que debe devolver en cada caso y **no** debería ser un 500 si el recurso no esta

Comment: Yo diría 404. Nunca un 5xx

Comment: Existen diferentes opiniones, hay quienes usarían un 200, ya que una consulta sin resultados también es un resultado OK. En fin, que la pregunta se basa en opiniones.

Comment: ya veo, sin embargo un 200 es OK pero el resultado es ```null``` por lo que no seria OK

Comment: Si no haces REST debe ser 200.

Comment: osea retorno 200 aunque la consulta no haya devuelto un valor correcto?

Comment: Esto es todo basado en opiniones.. tu back anduvo bien y respondio correctamente, por lo tanto seria un 200.. Que no haya datos, no quiere decir que fallo. Es muy diferente que falle por algo, a que no haya datos.... que no haya datos, es en si un dato valido.

Comment: Si el valor es nulo, y no un array vacio... deberia ser 400, la request esta mal hecha.

Comment: Cuando se habla de APIs REST se tiende a usar los códigos de estado HTTP para portar información sobre el resultado de la petición. Aunque es perfectamente posible responder a todo con 200 Ok (y luego por ejemplo enviar un JSON que contenga `{ "error": "El dato no se ha encontrado" }`, esto no se considera _RESTful_. Más correcto es usar un código de estado que indique la naturaleza del problema. Pedir un dato que no se encuentra en la base de datos es para mi un "Not found" y por tanto un 404. [No soy el único que opina esto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11746894/1264820)

Comment: HTTP es un protocolo de transferencia/transmisión de capa de aplicación. ¿Quién esperas que consuma el mensaje: una aplicación o un usuario?, ¿Quién es el destinatario (browser, javascript, servicio web, usuario, etc)? Los mensajes de negocio/usuario van en lo que algunos autores llaman la capa de usuario; incluso hay bromas sobre la capa-8. Si haces REST tiene sentido manejar los códigos HTTP tal cual, sino, depende. Si bien no es un crimen "copiarlos", o hacer un "pase directo", tendrías que cuestionarte si esos códigos son suficientes para los usuarios, que normalmente necesitan mas que eso

Comment: Esto da para guerra santa. 500 es error de servidor, no aplica en ningún caso. 4xx es error en la petición. ¿Será coherente que una búsqueda válida que entrega un resultado válido (conjunto vacío) tenga la misma respuesta que una url mal escrita? Lo segundo sí es un error de cliente.